# FormEmailer is sending emails from my address instead of FormEmailer

Tags: google-apps-script

I have had formemailer setup the same way for over a year and have never had this problem.  I have not changed anything but now all of a sudden it has started sending all form responses with my email address in the from field.  How do I fix this it has happened on 3 different forms that we have.  Thanks

Comment: This question is not related to programming and therefore Stackoverflow is not the place for it. You should ask this on FormEmailer's [discussion group](https://sites.google.com/site/formemailer/group).

Comment: I went to the discussion group before this and could not find how to add a discussion.  I found the email address it had in about and tried to email that and it didn't work came back as invalid address.  I looked up help on this and it brought me here. Sorry I just want help anyway I can get it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are seeing is due to [issue 2004](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2004). Please star the issue to be notified of updates to it. FormEmailer is probably a victim of this bug

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this problem myself and I'm glad to say I know how to fix this, and *it does involve some javascript coding*.

If you're having emails sent to you that must mean you have set up an automatic trigger(time-driven) and you have set up the settings to send emails to your address (for testing, I assume?) If you have an email address column you want to send emails to, that should be the column in which a placeholder references.

To stop sending blank emails to yourself in the thousands, you have to adjust the code so that it knows when to trigger! The original code does not account for when to stop emailing on an automatic trigger.

Line 209: `var status = c.fs.getRange(2,1,last-1,1).getValues();`

Line 209 is defining a variable within your monitor function. This variable "status" is getting the values in a specified range. Specifically, it is getting the current form sheet range. Google apps script has 4 different ways of writing getRange(), and this case has 4 arguments like this: `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`

The original code as is is saying, "From my current form sheet, start from the second row and first column, go all the way to the last row, and do all of this for an entire one column (column 1)".

But what if you have some data on rows 2:5 for columns B:Z (2:26 in javascript), and you have no data on rows 6 and beyond? You're emails will be sent for rows 2:5, and you'll receive error messages for lines 6:1000 or so (whatever "last" is) in column 1(javascript) or column 0 (excel/google sheet); in other words, column A will update with hundreds of error messages and depending on your settings you may have received hundreds of blank emails!

Update Line 209 precisely at the last argument of getRange(), where you specify how many columns you want to collect data. Choose up to the column where you know there will *always* be data, such as a Timestamp column if you're using google forms: var status = c.fs.getRange(2,1,last-1,***1***).getValues();

You've just set up a reference column(s) to check whether there is data to be emailed! Now, the next code is your for loop which checks status line by line, or row by row. In the code at Line 211 you are setting the condition when to run your email function called "doIt".

As is, Line 211 `if( status[i][0] === '' )` says "If status, at the first column, is equal to blank... then run  function doIt". But column A is not the column where my data lives! Column A is where my email statuses and error messages live. This condition is only preventing resending emails that have already been sent, or from sending emails where there has been an error.

Here is what your if statement should look like at Line 211:

```
if( status[i][0] === '' && status[i][YOUR REFERENCE COLUMN] !== '' )
  doIt_(i+2);
if( status[i][0] === '' && status[i][YOUR REFERENCE COLUMN] === '' )
  return;
```

This statement is saying, "If status at my first column is blank AND my reference column is not blank, then run my email function doIt...If status at my first column is blank AND my reference column is blank, then stop the for loop."

Save your code. You have just updated your code to accept automatic triggers! Set your time driven trigger and give it a test run!

Answer (score 0):

Google had an app engine failure sometime on Friday, October 26 around 9:30am CDT.  The last time I had a scripted email send with the name variable successfully changed was between 11:33pm Oct. 25, 2012 and 12:16pm Oct. 26...

I think these events may be related somehow - either way, they are all on Google's end...